# Audio/Media resource requests pending forever

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have an issue while playing my audio elements. When I spam click on them (and not only then) after some time the requests start pending forever and all requests after them as well. My audio elements have preload attribute set to "none" to limit data transfer (since playlists contain up to 500 songs). I have no idea what is the cause.

What might be important; I play each audio element manually via JS. When next is to play, I pause() the current one and play() the next one. Don't use load() method anywhere.
[image: pending requests]

I want pending resources to load and play.

**Seems to be only Chrome problem????**

Comment: Post JavaScript and HTML as a [mcve], please.

Answer (score 0):

@Rok

Yes. I just took the wrong approach - for each song I rendered a new audio tag.

The best approach is to have 1 audio tag per page, and then you change the "src" attribute dynamically with Javascript.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).